# Remove small background (black) regions within an image

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, image-processing

Attached is the image. I was able to get rid of the background region across the boundary but the background region within the image is still persistent. Is there any method that can get rid of the small background regions within an image. Thank you.[image]

Comment: What about photoshopping it? ;-)

Comment: @Dimple Bhuta you can't remove this black from the image with HTML or css, you have to do use the photoshop or some other image editing software

Comment: Besides photoshop is there any image processing algorithm that can be used generally.  I am not involved in HTML or css. I am sorry I will remove those tags

Comment: Are you sure that the background color is always going to be **black** and there would **NO** black patch in the foreground ornament ?

Comment: ?Or can you set the background color to something like `Blue`

Comment: @ZdaR- the background color isn't always black but the grab cut method i used for image segmentation gives almost pretty good results around the boundary of the object. But it doesn't tackle the problem within object background. Also, setting to another color doesn't make much difference. the main problem here is to remove smaller background regions within the foreground image. Irrespective of the color or shape where the background appears

Comment: Yes, you are right there, grabcut preserves the small background patches inside the foreground image. This problem could however be solved by thresholding the image and then segmenting the background, **assuming** that the background color would not be present in the foreground(ornament)

Comment: I have tried that but thresholding is not the best option in my case as alot of other images have similar colors. And applying threshold disturbs the foreground image too. I had read about background subtraction, I need to try that. But if there is any other method that deals only with smaller parts within an image that would be great

Comment: @DimpleBhuta If there is no assumptions to make here, it is impossible to do your task. If  the background is always of some known color, for example, then It may work, but you can not make a computer decide which part of that image are background and which not. I even though that the black things where part of the jewel in the beginning .

Comment: @AnderBiguri Thank you for your comment. I understand it would be impossible for the algorithm to decide on the background color. I had thought of implementing manual input from the user. As in, with mouseoncallback function in opencv select background areas. Also the background color will  uniform (meaning a color with varying areas of brightness or darkness). I was thinking about implementing GMMs to models the background areas and according classify and subtract it. Like a pattern recognition. I wanted to know if there any other techniques like segmentation specified by ZdaR that can help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a simple workaround for such issue, The basic idea is to segment the Image in RGB colorspace to filter out the black part left in the image, which may be simply implemented as :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 

ornament_image = cv2.imread("/Users/anmoluppal/Desktop/outputs/ornament.jpg")

#Considering the black range of background pixels
thresh = cv2.inRange(ornament_image, np.array([0, 0, 0]), np.array([55, 55, 55]))

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

cv2.drawContours(ornament_image, contours, -1, (255,255,255), -1)
#Replace the contours with the white color same as the background
```

[image]

But this removes some very small black portions in the ornament image, for preserving such parts we could filter out some contours by sorting them on the basis of contour area as

```
thresh = cv2.inRange(ornament_image, np.array([0, 0, 0]), np.array([55, 55, 55]))

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

contours = sorted(contours, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[:len(contours)/20]

cv2.drawContours(ornament_image, contours, -1, (255,255,255), -1)
```

**NOTE :** This method may preserve some black background noise as well

[image]

Further improvements:

- **YCrCb Segmentation** : If you are not happy with RGB segmentation then you may also try YCrCb segmentation of the given image, which is generally used in digital images.
- **Masking** : You may have noticed this as well that the black color inside the **Green Gem** of the ornament has also merged with the background due to black patch inside it, This can be removed by creating a mask which would hinder any segmentation in the given ROI, so the necessary details are preserved, However this requires human intervention.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I will definitely try it out and post if it works or anyother idea that can be implemented. Have you ever tried bayesian matting. In the grabcut paper it was specified that in the areas where grabcut fails it can be helpful? I wanted to know whether anyone have ever implemented it on their images. Once again thank you.

Comment: I have heard about it but never thought of implementing, Would read on that, In the meanwhile you may try the `Further improvements` or try some Other techniques that come to your mind

Comment: sure thats great. I am also trying to work on it and try other methods. Also, I am attaching your code written in C++ with manual mask added just in case if someone wants to try it out

Answer (score 0):

The above code in c++ and manual mask added.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

Mat thresh, hierarchy;

void onMouse( int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* imgptr ){
    if ( flags == (EVENT_FLAG_CTRLKEY + EVENT_FLAG_LBUTTON) ) //Sure Background - Red
        {

       Mat & img = (*(Mat*)imgptr); // first cast, then deref
       Point pt1 = Point(x, y);
       circle(img, pt1, 7, Scalar(0,0,255), -1, 8);
       imshow("Mark Image", img);
       waitKey(1);
        }
}

int main ()
{
    int i =0;

    Mat src = imread("C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/computervisionproject/segmentation/segmentation/Final_window.jpg",1);
    Mat image = src.clone();

    namedWindow("Mark Image",WINDOW_NORMAL);
    setMouseCallback("Mark Image",onMouse, &image);
    imshow("Mark Image",image);

    while(1){
    char c=waitKey();
    if(c=='s'){
    inRange(image, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0), cv::Scalar(55, 55, 55), thresh);

    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
    findContours(thresh,contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE ,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
    //findContours(thresh,contours, CV_RETR_TREE ,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
    cout <<"Hello"<<endl;


    drawContours(src, contours, -1, Scalar(255,255,255), -1);

    namedWindow( "Display window", WINDOW_NORMAL );
    imshow( "Display window", src);
    }
    }

    waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```